# MySQL WHERE if NULL select another column

Tags: mysql

This is my mysql table

```
id      date_created                date_active
1       2014-06-07 18:24:38     NULL
2       2014-06-07 18:24:38     2014-06-07 18:24:38
3       2014-06-07 18:24:38     2014-06-07 18:24:38
4       2014-06-07 18:24:38     NULL
5       2014-06-07 18:24:38     NULL
6       2014-06-07 18:24:38     NULL
7       2014-06-07 18:24:38     2014-06-07 18:24:38
8       2014-06-07 18:24:38     2014-06-07 18:24:38
9       2014-06-07 18:24:38     2014-06-07 18:24:38
10      2014-06-07 18:24:38     NULL
```

How to set WHERE to select another column if the column is NULL?

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE date_active = 'value'.
```

If date_active is NULL it should use the date_created column.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally speaking you can use [`COALESCE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE COALESCE(date_active,date_created) = 'value'
```

However this is not [sargable](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable). Depending on indexes available you may find the following

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE date_active = 'value' OR 
      (date_active IS NULL AND date_created = 'value')
```

Or even

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE date_active = 'value'
UNION ALL
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE  (date_active IS NULL AND date_created = 'value')
```

Performs better